# Moving Short Description Text into Long Description Area On Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, php-5.4

I'm attempting to move my product's SHORT description into my long description, without merging the two during import. I attempted to move the following code into my description.phtml file, but it just breaks the page at the description area.

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
    <div class="short-description">
        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Any idea how to effectively move the short description to just above the main description area? Do I need to do anything with the XML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code at very top of the file `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template\catalog\product\view\description.phtml`.

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
    <div class="short-description">
        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

<br />
```

You are done. For full reference of the modified file, **[you can refer this](https://gist.github.com/progammer-rkt/58d240946f01071f2ae8)**.

Answer (score 1):

Add your code inside the description if statement in the `product/view.phtml` file

```
<?php if ($_product->getDescription()):?>
    //my short description code
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: sorry done via mobile but anyway just look at the view.phtml file and find where the long description is output

Comment: But the long description is output in the description.phtml file. If I attempt to add the short description there, it breaks the page.